# Stripes in drywall

Tags: drywall

I have two 1/8" stripes about 2" apart running vertically from ceiling to vanity cover down one wall in bathroom.  I have painted, then used two coats of primer then painted again.  Then used Zinsseer bullseye 1-2-3 primer and painted again.  Then used Valspar stainblocking primer sealer all to no avail.

Comment: A picture might help, but it sounds like you need to sand, skim coat or both at this point.

Answer (score 1):

If that much paint hasn't solved your problem then you are probably going to want to putty and sand until you have a smooth surface then paint again.